# How can I implement neural networks on scikit-learn 0.17.1?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, neural-network

I want to implement Neural Networks on scikit-learn. But I have the 0.17.1 version. If I upgrade it to 0.18, that means that all my previous code will not work. Am I wrong? Is there a way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scikit-learn releases an explanation of all its changes at each new version. Look at [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html).

Some of your functions might be **deprecated** in the new version and you will have to readapt them using the new features.

But you won't loose all your previous code. Don't worry ! Go and update `sklearn` !